# Notification using Firebase cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am working on an android app which uses a hosted orient db as database and i need to send notifications to all the android devices. Is it possible to get notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.If so please guide me how can i achieve that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: yaa it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's possible you can send notification to all connected device. You can read out full description and how to send notification here 
:- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple